# Collatz Sequence: Which number is the biggest?

Tags: java

So I have written code for the Collatz Sequence, but I want to be able to identify and print out the largest number that appears in the sequence. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollatzSequence {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,ts = 0;

        System.out.print("This is the Lothar Collatz Sequnce. Please enter the starting number.\n>");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();

        do {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            else {
                n = n*3 + 1;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        ts++;
        }
        while (n != 1);       
        System.out.println("Terminated after "+ts+" steps.");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a variable called `max`.  Set it initially equal to `n`.  In each step, check if `n > max` and if it is, set `max` to `n`.